# Android fragments on stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, master-detail, android-memory

I got a problem. I have master detail view and i replace fragments by fragment manager. It works but after changing some of them i got a memory error. And fragment doesn't have any pictures inside(every replacing fragment have a quite big image).
The question is how to delete those fragment from stack that I'm not using anymore? Preventing memory errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
how to delete those fragment from stack that I'm not using anymore?
```

You add to the back state from the `FragmentTransaction` and remove from the backstack using `FragmentManager` pop methods:

```
FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
trans.remove(myFrag);
trans.commit();
manager.popBackStack();
```